# How to find the size of the file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am using multer for uploading my images and documents but this time I want to restrict uploading if the size of the image is >2mb. How can I find the size of the file of the document? So far I tried as below but not working.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, common.upload.student);
      },
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {  
        console.log(file.size+'!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')======>'Undefined'
        var ext = '';
        var name = '';
        if (file.originalname) {
          var p = file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.');
          ext = file.originalname.substring(p + 1);
          var firstName = file.originalname.substring(0, p + 1);
          name = Date.now() + '_' + firstName;
          name += ext;
        }
        var filename = file.originalname;
        uploadImage.push({ 'name': name });
        callback(null, name);
  }
});
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: how are you calling `filename` function

Comment: Hi brk,I am not sure about that but i am using callback for that.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

To get a file's size in megabytes:

```
var fs = require("fs"); // Load the filesystem module
var stats = fs.statSync("myfile.txt")
var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
// Convert the file size to megabytes (optional)
var fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / (1024*1024);
```

or in bytes:

```
function getFilesizeInBytes(filename) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(filename);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}
```

Comment: For people searching in 2020+, we now have `(await fs.promises.stat(file)).size`.

Comment: Links to official docs for convenience: [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback) and [fs.promises.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_stat_path_options)

Comment: To convert to MB it should be `fileSizeInBytes / (1024 * 1000)`. See the last example on https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-file-stats.

Comment: @garrettmills whats wrong with `fs.statSync(file).size` compared to your  `(await fs.promises.stat(file)).size`? i dont see advantage.. -> ok, i read a little, it seems like it makes sense when there are other promises that can happen while waiting, as it is nonblocking - however, if you have single-task single-promise code, there is no need to do await, so its not for people 2020+, its for people 2020+ doing multi-promise code (or just not caring and having safer code)

Answer (score 26):

If you use ES6 and deconstructing, finding the size of a file in bytes only takes 2 lines (one if the fs module is already declared!):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {size} = fs.statSync('path/to/file');
```

Note that this will fail if the size variable was already declared. This can be avoided by renaming the variable while deconstructing using a colon:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {size: file1Size} = fs.statSync('path/to/file1');
const {size: file2Size} = fs.statSync('path/to/file2');
```

Comment: But how do you display this?     console.log(stats.size()) is failing.

Comment: @webs Are you perhaps commenting on the wrong answer? I didn't use stats in my examples. As for my first example, You can output the result with console.log(size);

Answer (score 7):

In addition, you can use the NPM filesize package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/filesize

This package makes things a little more configurable.

```
var fs = require("fs"); //Load the filesystem module

var filesize = require("filesize"); 

var stats = fs.statSync("myfile.txt")

var fileSizeInMb = filesize(stats.size, {round: 0});
```

For more examples:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/filesize#examples

Comment: the size is in KB, not MB; stats.size gives bytes, filesize(stats.size, {round: 0}) give KB, the output - if you have stats.size 218871 it makes   filesize(stats.size, {round: 0}) = '214 KB' ```// list files with sizes:
fs.readdir('.', (err, files) => { files.forEach(file => { 
   var stats = fs.statSync(file);
   var fileSizeInKb = filesize(stats.size, {round: 0});
   console.log('%s  --- %s  ', file, fileSizeInKb); 
}); });```

Comment: @SashaBond nah. I think filesize is a module for human readable values. Depending on the file size if it's small or huge it will display the size using KB or MB, try it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a current answer with native packages, here's how to get mb size of a file without blocking the event loop using `fs` (specifically, [fsPromises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_stat_path_options)) and `async`/`await`:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const BYTES_PER_MB = 1024 ** 2;

// paste following snippet inside of respective `async` function
const fileStats = await fs.stat('/path/to/file');
const fileSizeInMb = fileStats.size / BYTES_PER_MB;
```

Answer (score 3):

The link by @gerryamurphy is broken for me, so I will link to a package I made for this.

https://github.com/dawsbot/file-bytes

The API is simple and should be easily usable:

```js
fileBytes('README.md').then(size => {
    console.log(`README.md is ${size} bytes`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this package from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-sizeof

The API is quite simple, and it gives you the file size in `SI` and `IEC` notation.

```js
const { sizeof } = require("file-sizeof");

const si = sizeof.SI("./testfile_large.mp4");
const iec = sizeof.IEC("./testfile_large.mp4");
```

And the resulting object represents the size from `B`(byte) up to `PB` (petabyte).

```js
interface ISizeOf {
  B: number;
  KB: number;
  MB: number;
  GB: number;
  TB: number;
  PB: number;
}
```